# android.graphics.Path doesn't render on device, but does render on simulator

Tags: android

On Android 4+, I have a simple point-to-point line that draws fine on Simulator, but fails to draw on mainstream devices (e.g. Samsung S3).

Is this a hardware bug? An OS bug? Or is there something wrong I'm doing? It's two lines of basic code :(.

Code:

```
Path pathToPaint = new Path(currentlyDisplayingRoute.path);
canvas.drawPath( pathToPaint, pathPaint);
```

Simulator:

> The path draws on screen at the correct place in correct color

Device:

> The path never draws

Comment: Turn off the GPU acceleration on device and give a try.

Comment: @faylon thanks. I checked, and the Google Android docs on hardware acceleration don't list Path(Path) as one of the "we didn't bother implementing it" methods, but I think you're right that it's the HW-accel codepath that is broken. You set me on the right track!

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: To be clear: Yes, it's caused by hardware acceleration bugs. But ... if I disable hardware-acceleration, I hit other (major) bugs in the Android software implementation of Canvas :(.

---

OK, so it turns out the core Android class "Path" is fundamentally broken :(.

There are two constructors. One of these constructors is "not implemented" on hardware. This is not documented. I'd consider this a showstopper bug - it creates no warnings, no errors, it just breaks the API and any apps that use it :(.

This constructor: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#Path%28android.graphics.Path%29

> public Path (Path src) Added in API level 1
>
> Create a new path, copying the contents from the src path.

...mustn't be used. Sigh.

Comment: There are really many problems when using hardware acceleration. Many methods cannot be used anymore.

Comment: @faylon - Yeah :(. So far I've been lucky, this is the first time I've hit a problem with the "standard" method calls. Previously I've only had problems with obscure/complicated features :(.